# Selecting values used by all identifiers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table which contains UserID and AppID. Now i need a select query which selects all appid's which are used by all userid's

For example:

```
UserID         AppID
1              35
1              42
2              35
2              42
3              35
3              77
```

In this example I would only want AppID 35 because it's used by all UserID's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do aggregation :

```
select appid
from table t
group by appid
having count(*) = (select count(distinct userid) from table);
```

Use `distinct` inside `count()` in case `appid` has duplicate userid.

Answer (score 1):

... or you may use correlated subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AppID
FROM sourcetable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM sourcetable t2
                   WHERE t1.AppID = t2.AppID
                     AND t1.UserID != t2.UserID )
```